# Auth on create resource causing routing problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to require auth before reaching the create resource and have seperated my resource routes accordingly.

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController', ['except' => ['store','edit','update','destroy','create']]);

Route::group(['before'=>'auth'], function() {
Route::resource('posts','PostsController', ['only' => ['store','edit','update','destroy','create']]);});
```

Now for some reason when going to posts/create it redirects me to the show route.  The auth is working fine on all other routes, and when create is removed it asks for login upon posting the create, but obviously I would like this section to be off limits regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use [controller filters](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters) instead.

This simplifies the routing to this:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

And in your post controller's constructor, you can configure the filter:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('index', 'show')));
}
```

Comment: Why would this work and it not working when doing it through routing?

I initially started doing it this way but thought it was better to keep it the routing.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to call `Route::resource()` twice. Just a guess, though. Didn't dive into your code that much...